# apple mach-o linker error linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors

When add Reachability file.H and file.m  in my project that time error occurs.
apple mach-o linker error linker command failed with exit code 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a compiler flag, "-fno-objc-arc", to the "Reachability.m" under "Compile Sources" in "Build phases"...

[image]

However this is just an educated guess, due to not having enough information...